# How to select loose vertices/edges and delete them?

Tags: vertices

I tried with <kbd>W</kbd> key and and using the cursor, but failed.

I want to remove the vertices/edges visible below (formerly belonging to the head), disconnected from the main body:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: I just came here to say that you are not John Carmack. John Carmack does not roll into Blender Stack Exchange opening with "i have blender".  When actual John Carmack wants to learn Blender he codes an AI clone of himself to do it for him and report back. He's certainly already done this. And even said clone knows better than to opt for the handle "John carmack". Nonetheless, good luck to you in your journey.

Comment: Yes, @Mentalist, and I'm actually not a wizard :D

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Fair enough. I hope I didn't come across as harsh. I felt compelled to give a playful jab for impersonation, but no ill will. (Also, you *are* a wizard.) OP: Don't worry - we really are friendly here! We don't bite.

Comment: impersonating anything john carmack is a normal name and im using it because its random and harms nobody, i'd rather stay in the shadows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also select the body with <kbd>L</kbd>, invert the selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> and delete with <kbd>X</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Z</kbd> key, switch to Wireframe mode; <kbd>C</kbd> key, paint the selection with the brush selection. then <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd>to grow selection. <kbd>X</kbd> key or <kbd>⌦ Del</kbd> to delete. If there's something left, you can try from menu *Select ‣ Select All by Trait ‣ Loose Geometry*.

Answer (score 2):

I just select all( <kbd>A</kbd> ), convert selection to faces( <kbd>3</kbd> ) so I only have faces selected, convert selection to edges( <kbd>2</kbd> ) - now I have only edges that belong to full faces selected, so no loose edges are selected so just invert selection( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>I</kbd> ) to select only those loose edges and delete edges. Same goes for vertices: if I select all vertices, convert selection to edges, and back to vertices, only vertices that are part of edges get selected so inverted selection is only loose vertices.

[image]